# What is the correct way to define one to many association in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the correct way to define one to many association in rails 5.we
have currently the following models.we have to define
products and categories tables such that one category has many products.

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category, index: true
end
```

Error:AssociationtypeMismatch

Comment: These are not migrations files, and there is no `index: true` option for `belongs_to`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, generate your models as so:

```
rails generate model Category title:string 

rails generate model Product title:string category_id:integer
```

this will create the two models with their migration files...

```
rake db:migrate # run migrations
```

and in **app/models**

```
# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
end

# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Comment: if i don't use dependent: :destroy then will it work?if it will work then why association mismatch popping out

Comment: yes, it will work but if you delete a category, its products will not deleted. you're probably getting `AssociationtypeMismatch` because `belongs_to` has no `index: true` option: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AssociationTypeMismatch.html

Comment: so should i add index: true in product.rb model